# Applying style to navigation submenu anchor tag text (sub menu item)

Tags: html, css

My goal is to apply a style to "In Stock"or "Finance Application" sub menu item. The goal is to change the font-size of the text (of all sub menu items).

I can apply styles to Inventory Main Navigation Item but no matter what I do - I just can't change the font-size of the sub menu items text.

```
<nav id="nav-wrap" class="nav-wrap2  mn4 darknavi"> 
<li id="menu-item-5603" class="menu-item"><a href="#" data-description=""><i class="fa-caret-down"></i>Inventory</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-5607" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type "><a href="#" data-description="">In Stock</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4907" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type "><a href=""#" data-description="">Finance Application</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</nav>
```

Comment: Element li not allowed as child of element nav in this context. It's not Validated.

Answer (score 0):

This will change the colour of the sub-menu items only:

`ul li a {color:#f00;}`

Answer (score 0):

```
.sub-menu li a {color:#f00;}
```

Using .sub-menu Class Selector. you can apply style only Sub menu.
and

Element li not allowed as child of element nav in this context. It's not Validated HTML